# Magento 2 - Move Menu Location

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I'm trying to move the navigation menu on a Magento 2 installation. I've created a child theme of the default blank theme and I want to move the navigation menu into the header of the site. At present I've accomplished it in CSS but I would rather move it in the code as it will be cleaner.

I've tried following other posts on this site along with the Magento Docs but all I seem to achieve is making the navigation menu disappear. Below is the code I'm using. It's probably something really small and stupid that I'm doing wrong but I was wondering if anyone out there could look at the code with a fresh set of eyes and spot the error of my ways ;)

Any help gratefully appreciated:

Code:

```
<move element="nav-sections" destination="page-header" after="block-search"/>
```

Thanks

Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you want to move it, the following moves it to the very top:

```
<move element="navigation.sections" destination="after.body.start"/>
```

In `htdocs/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml` you can finde some destinations that fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Nito. The file location for the destination references helped. I wanted to move it into the header content.